# Enzyme Shallow Rendered Component is Undefined

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to test a stateless React component using Jest + Enzyme, but keep getting an error. I tried to test the component by testing its parent component, which is `Tables.js` and imports and renders this component as `<Table />`, but got the same error.

```
TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
at Function.keys (<anonymous>)

  at table (src/components/UI/Table/Table.js:29:27)
  at Object.type (node_modules/enzyme-adapter-react-16/build/ReactSixteenAdapter.js:329:38)
  at ReactShallowRenderer.render (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer-shallow.development.js:145:34)
  at node_modules/enzyme-adapter-react-16/build/ReactSixteenAdapter.js:333:37
  at withSetStateAllowed (node_modules/enzyme-adapter-utils/build/Utils.js:110:16)
  at Object.render (node_modules/enzyme-adapter-react-16/build/ReactSixteenAdapter.js:332:70)
  at new ShallowWrapper (node_modules/enzyme/build/ShallowWrapper.js:170:22)
  at shallow (node_modules/enzyme/build/shallow.js:21:10)
  at setup (src/containers/Tables/Tables.test.js:14:46)
  at Object.it (src/containers/Tables/Tables.test.js:25:9)
      at Promise (<anonymous>)
  at Promise.resolve.then.el (node_modules/p-map/index.js:46:16)
      at <anonymous>
  at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:169:7)
```

**Table.js**

```
import React from 'react'

import TableRow from './TableRow/TableRow'
import './Table.scss'

const getMaxPlaysInPercentage = (dataArr) => {
    let currentMax = 0
    let total = 0
    let currentMaxTitle = ''

    dataArr.forEach(obj => {
        const plays = Number(obj.plays)
        const keyForTitle = Object.keys(obj)[0]
        total += plays
        if(currentMax < plays) {
            currentMax = plays
            currentMaxTitle = obj[keyForTitle]
        }
    })
    const maxInPercentage = (currentMax / total * 100).toFixed(2)

    return {
        maxInPercentage, 
        currentMaxTitle
    }
}

const table = (props) => {
    const titles = Object.keys(props.titles).map((title, index) => {
        const key = `val${index}`
        return (
            <th
                key={title+key} 
                className="analytics-title analytics-table-cell"
                onClick={(e)=>props.sortColumnsHandler(props.tableName, title)}>
                {props.titles[title]}
            </th>
        )
    })

    const maxPlays = getMaxPlaysInPercentage(props.data)

    const contentRows = props.data.map((prop, index)=>{
        const key = `${props.tableName}-row${index}`
        return (<TableRow
                    key={key} 
                    tableName={props.tableName}
                    titles={props.titles}
                    valuePairs={prop}/>)
    })

    return (
        <section className="analytics-table">
            <h2>{props.header}</h2>
            <p>{maxPlays.maxInPercentage}% from {maxPlays.currentMaxTitle}</p>
            <table  className="analytics-content">
                <tbody>
                    <tr className="analytics-titles">
                        {titles}
                    </tr>
                    {contentRows} 
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </section>
    )
}

export default table
```

**Table.test.js**

```
import React from 'react';

import { configure, shallow } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

import Table from './Table';

configure({adapter: new Adapter()});

function setup() {
    const props = {
        sortColumnHandler: jest.fn()
    }
    const enzymeWraper = shallow(<Table />)

    return {
        props,
        enzymeWraper
    }
}


describe('Table', () => {
    it('should render', () => {
        const { enzymeWraper }  = setup()

    })
})
```

Comment: @brian-lives-outdoors maybe?

Comment: Either add some default values for your props, or do what @brian-lives-outdoors suggested.  As soon as your component tried to render you call `Object.keys(props.titles).map`.  In your test, props is `undefined`.  When you try `props.title` this will throw an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Table` component uses some `props` that it needs to be provided:

```
const titles = {
  // add test titles here
}
const data = [
  // add test data here
]
const enzymeWraper = shallow(
  <Table 
    titles={titles} 
    data={data}
    tableName="Test Table Name"
    header="Test Header"
  />
);
```

Comment: This is unfortunately the answer. I provided deprecated props and it started returning undefined.